# laravel 5.6 convert hashed password to normal password?

Tags: laravel

There is no option to convert hashed text back to plain text. Thats the reason why we use that method to store password - only the author of a password can know the real value - nobody else (developers and someone who can stole passwords). The popular method used to break hashed password is called "brute force attack" and is based on comparing already known hashed values of popular passwords to existing ones in database.

Now i need to show current password when user change password. but hash password cant not return back.
how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to show current password. It should be entered by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> convert hashed password to normal password?

- **Encryption** is a two-way function; what is encrypted can be decrypted with the proper key.
- **Hashing** is a one-way function that scrambles plain text to produce a unique message digest. With a properly designed algorithm, there is no way to reverse the hashing process to reveal the original password.

[image]

---

> Now i need to show current password when user change password. but hash password cant not return back. how to solve this issue?

**You do not need to show the password to anyone, including the owner of the password.**

If you want to check, you can use `check` method, allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash.

```php
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```